# IIS URL Rewrite 2 installed but can't find it

Tags: windows-7, iis, url, asp.net, url-rewriting

My company had their website built in ASP.NET, and for SEO purposes we want to change the URLs and asked the company who built the site if we could do it ourselves. They said use [IIS URL Rewrite 2](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

I installed it on my computer, but when looking at my programs and through my computer I can't find it.

Please excuse my ignorance.

Does any one know where it would be? 
And when I find it, any tips on using it etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the page you have linked to, you have explanations on using this product.

Particularly useful seems to be the article [Using URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/) which explains its use.

From the doc, one needs to register a provider, then use it. The providers and rewrite rules are found in IIS as below. I suggest that you study the docs before working with the product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the end of [the page you have linked to](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), you have links to articles explaining [how to use the URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/).

Generally, you would need to install the URL Rewrite Module into IIS, then configure one or more rewrite rules using either **IIS Manager** or by manually editing **web.config** files.

#### 1. Locate and Open the URL Rewrite UI within IIS Manager

[image]

#### 2. You can manage *inbound* and *outbound* rewrite rules

[image]

#### 3. Here is a simple example of a regex match and rewrite to a subweb

[image]

#### 4. The resulting rewrite rules created in *web.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule001" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^services/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/my/services/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is enough to rewrite most URLs. It's not necessary to configure any providers in 99.999% of most real-world scenarios. They exist only for advanced rewriting needs (dynamic rewriting, for example, rather than a static rule.)

It's primarily intended by Microsoft that you simply define rewrite rules that meet your needs as shown above.

Hope this helps others.